# Are communities available in the Salesforce1 mobile app?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

Can we collaborate communitites in salesforce with salesforce1App ?

I have configured community and created salesforce1app separately . Now I need both to be collaborate i.e. community have to be opened in mobile version .

Answer (score 6):

Communities will only be available in the browser version of the Salesforce1 app (one/one.app) and only then with the Spring '14 release, which was just postponed.

One thing that I've been exploring is a hybrid mobile wrapper of Communities in Salesforce1 using the mobile SDK. This seems entirely possible and not terribly difficult.

Comment: Hi @greenstork! today they are working in my pre-release org!! I didn't change anything at all!! I just re-enter went to the comunity that is private at the moment and did exactly the same!. Then now it is working! You are right thanks!! ( however still having problems trying to create new Global Actions in my spring 14 :( )

Comment: Great to hear, exciting times ahead with Communities in S1.

Comment: Totally true @greenstork! I'm really looking forward to see them in the App. Thanks a lot again! :)